# Can logic analyser show high impedance state?

Tags: digital-logic, high-impedance

Quick question: are there logic analysers that can show us high impedance state in circuit? I could only find information about different voltage levels for TTL and CMOS, but couldn't find clean information about high impedance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen older logic analysers that were capable of showing if an input signal was in a disallowed state.  That is: the input voltage was in the region between a defined logic LO level and a defined logic HI level.

This was many years ago and I don't recall which logic analyser it was - I'm guessing Tektronix but I honestly don't remember.

Certainly the little logic analyser I use today (Open Bench Logic Sniffer from Dangerous Prototypes / Seeed Studio) does NOT have that capability.

Do note that even if the logic analyser *DOES* have that capability, *something* has to make the input signal go into that disallowed state when the signal is in the high-impedance state.  That may require you to add external voltage dividers to each of the inputs to drag the signals into that disallowed state when high-impedance.